# OpenShift create template from existing setup

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I was trying to generate a template from my existing setup with

```
oc export dc,svc,bc --selector="microservice=imagesvc" -o yaml --as-template=imagesvc
```

The problem is that the template points the container source to my reigstry. I would like to modify the template in a way that the build configuration is building the container from source, then attaches it to the deploymentconfig. How can I achieve something like that?

This is the config I currently have. When I apply I get various errors. As an example in Builds I get "Invalid output reference"

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: imagesvc
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app: gcsimageupload
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: gcsimageupload
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: gcsimageupload
    strategy:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
      resources: {}
      rollingParams:
        intervalSeconds: 1
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        timeoutSeconds: 600
        updatePeriodSeconds: 1
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: gcsimageupload
          deploymentconfig: gcsimageupload
          microservice: imagesvc
      spec:
        containers:
        - imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          name: gcsimageupload
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /secret
            name: gcsimageupload-secret
            readOnly: true
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        volumes:
        - name: gcsimageupload-secret
          secret:
            defaultMode: 420
            secretName: gcsimageupload-secret
    test: false
    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - gcsimageupload
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: gcsimageupload:latest
          namespace: web
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
  status:
    availableReplicas: 0
    latestVersion: 0
    observedGeneration: 0
    replicas: 0
    unavailableReplicas: 0
    updatedReplicas: 0
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app: imagesvc
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: imagesvc
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: imagesvc
    strategy:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
      resources: {}
      rollingParams:
        intervalSeconds: 1
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        timeoutSeconds: 600
        updatePeriodSeconds: 1
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: imagesvc
          deploymentconfig: imagesvc
          microservice: imagesvc
      spec:
        containers:
        - imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          name: imagesvc
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    test: false
    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - imagesvc
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: imagesvc:latest
          namespace: web
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
  status:
    availableReplicas: 0
    latestVersion: 0
    observedGeneration: 0
    replicas: 0
    unavailableReplicas: 0
    updatedReplicas: 0
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app: imaginary
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: imaginary
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: imaginary
      deploymentconfig: imaginary
    strategy:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
      resources: {}
      rollingParams:
        intervalSeconds: 1
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        timeoutSeconds: 600
        updatePeriodSeconds: 1
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: imaginary
          deploymentconfig: imaginary
          microservice: imagesvc
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: h2non/imaginary
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          name: imaginary
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    test: false
    triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - imaginary
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: imaginary:latest
          namespace: web
      type: ImageChange
  status:
    availableReplicas: 0
    latestVersion: 0
    observedGeneration: 0
    replicas: 0
    unavailableReplicas: 0
    updatedReplicas: 0
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: gcsimageupload
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: gcsimageupload
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: gcsimageupload
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
      service.alpha.openshift.io/dependencies: '[{"name":"gcsimageupload","namespace":"","kind":"Service"},{"name":"imaginary","namespace":"","kind":"Service"}]'
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: imagesvc
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: imagesvc
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: imagesvc
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: imaginary
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: imaginary
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: 9000-tcp
      port: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: imaginary
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: BuildConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: gcsimageupload
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: gcsimageupload
  spec:
    nodeSelector: null
    output:
      to:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: gcsimageupload:latest
    postCommit: {}
    resources: {}
    runPolicy: Serial
    source:
      git:
        ref: master
        uri: https://github.com/un1x86/openshift-ms-gcsFileUpload.git
      type: Git
    strategy:
      sourceStrategy:
        env:
        - name: GCS_PROJECT
          value: ${GCS_PROJECT_ID}
        - name: GCS_KEY_FILENAME
          value: ${GCS_KEY_FILENAME}
        - name: GCS_BUCKET
          value: ${GCS_BUCKET}
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: nodejs:4
          namespace: openshift
      type: Source
    triggers:
    - github:
        secret: f9928132855c5a30
      type: GitHub
    - generic:
        secret: 77ece14f810caa3f
      type: Generic
    - imageChange: {}
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
  status:
    lastVersion: 0
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: BuildConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: imagesvc
      microservice: imagesvc
    name: imagesvc
  spec:
    nodeSelector: null
    output:
      to:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: imagesvc:latest
    postCommit: {}
    resources: {}
    runPolicy: Serial
    source:
      git:
        ref: master
        uri: https://github.com/un1x86/openshift-ms-imagesvc.git
      type: Git
    strategy:
      sourceStrategy:
        env:
        - name: IMAGINARY_APPLICATION_DOMAIN
          value: http://imaginary:9000
        - name: GCSIMAGEUPLOAD_APPLICATION_DOMAIN
          value: http://gcsimageupload:8080
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: nodejs:4
          namespace: openshift
      type: Source
    triggers:
    - generic:
        secret: 945da12357ef35cf
      type: Generic
    - github:
        secret: 18106312cfa8e2d1
      type: GitHub
    - imageChange: {}
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
  status:
    lastVersion: 0
parameters:
    - description: "GCS Project ID"
      name: GCS_PROJECT_ID
      value: ""
      required: true
    - description: "GCS Key Filename"
      name: GCS_KEY_FILENAME
      value: /secret/keyfile.json
      required: true
    - description: "GCS Bucket name"
      name: GCS_BUCKET
      value: ""
      required: true
```

Comment: When I run `oc export` with my 3.11 installation on my laptop, I get a message as `export` is not a known command. This command seems to be valid only in 4.2. Therefore, I am confused as to how `oc export` worked almost 2.5 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two imagestreams named "imagesvc" and "gcsimageupload". You could do it by cli "oc create is " or by adding to the template:

```
- kind: ImageStream
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: <name>
  spec:
    lookupPolicy:
      local: false
```

Comment: The easier way is to export 'is' as well as 'dc,svc,bc' to start with. There will still need to be a few fix ups done though as the export mechanism still leaves references in to the image registry, rather than referencing properly the image stream. If OP can update question with export of 'is' included, then can point out other changes required.